# Analytic variety is a countable union of complex manifolds

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

In an article on real analytic manifolds I came across the following remark:

Let $W$ be a purely $k$-dimensional analytic subvariety of a domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $S$ be its singular locus. Let $V$ be an open relatively compact subset of $W$.

Here is the remark:

$\overline{V} \cap S$ is contained in the singular locus $S$ which, being an analytic variety of dimension $k-1$ , is ( by induction) a countable union of complex manifolds of dimensions $ \le k-1$.

Could you tell me why is it so?

Here is what I've found in [Lojasiewicz's book "Introduction to complex analytic geometry"](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=%C5%81ojasiewicz&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def), page 217, thanks to Theo:

> $9.$ The decomposition of an analytic set $V \subset M$ into simple
>   components  is the representation of $V$ as the union of a locally
>   finite family of analytic  subsets $V_i$ of $M$ which are irreducible
>   and such that $V_i \not\subset V_j$ for $i \neq j$.
>
> (Such  a family is always countable; see D. 1.) According to theorem
>   $4$ below, such  a decomposition always exists and is unique. The sets
>   $V_i$ are called simple  components of the set $V$.

And here's the theorem:

> THEOREM 4 (On the decomposition into simple components).
>
> Every analytic set $V \subset M$ has a unique decomposition into
>   simple components: $V =  \bigcup V_i$. Then
>   $$V_i \setminus V^* = V_i^0 \setminus V^* =  V_i^0 \setminus \bigcup_{m \neq i}V_m $$
>
> and all these sets are submanifolds, open and dense in $V_j^o $ (and
>   hence also in $V_i$), and form the family of all connected components
>   of the set $V^0$. Therefore  the simple components of the analytic set
>   $V$ are precisely the closures of the connected components of the set
>   $V^0$. We have the formulae : 
>   $$ V^* = \bigcup V^*_i \cup \bigcup_{i,j} (V_i \cap V_j)$$ and 
>   $$V^0 = \bigcup_i (V_i^0 \setminus \bigcup_{m \neq i} V_m)$$

I think this solves the problem. Am I right?

Comment: Can you at least refer us to the article you were reading? It seems the induction is described there...

Comment: @Theo Of course, here it is: http://bookzz.org/book/2126595/79cf5c , the remark is on page 16. You are right, there is written "by induction" in brackets. But I still do not know how to prove that.

Comment: @Theo I've found this theorem in Chirka's Complex Analytic Sets: Let $ f: A \to Y$ be a holomorphic map of a $p$-dimensional  
analytic set $A$ into a complex manifold. Then $ f (A)$ is contained in an (at most) countable 
union of analytic sets on $Y$, of dimensions not exceeding $\dim f$. Moreover, for any 
$q \ge p - \dim f $ the set $\{w \in Y: \dim f^{-1} (w) \ge q \} $ is contained in a countable union of 
analytic sets of dimensions not exceeding $p - q$. It looks similar. Do you think it's helpful here?

Comment: Here $\dim f = \max _{z \in A} \dim _z f$ and $\dim _z f =\dim _z A - \dim_z f^{-1}(f(z))$ - it is the codimension of the fiber.

Comment: It seems that every analytic variety has such a countable filtration... Moreover, the singular locus is an analytic variety so that should cover it... Look at theorem 5.29 (page 19) of these notes: http://www.massey.math.neu.edu/Massey/Massey_preprints/sing_notes.pdf     It doesn't give proofs but references to proofs. Let me know if you still have trouble and I might try and write up something...

Comment: @Theo Thank you a lot for those notes. I don't think I would have ever found it. I've written down an excerpt from Lojasiewicz's book to which the author of the notes refers to. I think the theorem is exactly the remark I quoted. Am I right? Or am I missing something? Could you look at it and tell me what you think about it?

Comment: No big deal, glad to help out and thanks for editting the question so that now we have a reference... I agree, I think the theorem covers it. You also need of course to know that the singular locus is an analytic variety, that is Theorem 1 page 211 in Lojasiewicz's book. Also, if you have a link for the book, could you put that online too? (I only found the notes...)

Comment: I've just added the link to the page where the book can be found. Thanks again!